# notmuch-mode very slow in emacs-mac-port (railwaycat)

Tags: osx, notmuch, emacs-mac-port

I run Emacs on Mac OSX, I'm trying to switch from [Emacs for Mac OSX](http://emacsformacosx.com) to [Emacs Mac Port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port).

I use [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/emacstips/) for email. It works perfectly on [Emacs for Mac OSX](http://emacsformacosx.com).

But on Emacs Mac Port, it's prohibitively slow. Also, the message list is messed up, double spaced and with strange boxes:

[image: display irregularities]

I'm using the exact same configuration as I do with Emacs for Mac OSX.

What's causing these problems, and how do I fix them?

Answer (score 1):

The square boxes are caused by the use of SVG images in `notmuch-tag-formats`. Why SVG images don't work correctly in emacs-mac-port I don't know. You could modify `notmuch-tag-formats` to avoid their use.

This doesn't explain the slowdown, which I don't see.

Comment: Current value of `notmuch-tag-formats` is `(("unread"
  (propertize tag 'face
              '(:foreground "red")))
 ("flagged"
  (propertize tag 'face
              '(:foreground "blue"))
  (notmuch-tag-format-image-data tag
                                 (notmuch-tag-star-icon))))`. What should I change it to?